# Dialog box without launching app activity in the background

Tags: android, dialog

I have an `IntentService` which triggers a `Dialog` box after an event of interest has occurred. But, each time the `Dialog` box is launched, the `MainActivity` of my app is launched in the background with the `Dialog` box in the foreground. Dismissing the `Dialog` gives the user access to the `Activity`.

Is there a way to launch only the `Dialog` without launching the `MainActivity` in the background. I want it to be like the messaging app which shows a dialog for quick reply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: POST Dialog in BroadcastReceiver class

Comment: **"I have an IntentService which triggers a Dialog box after an event of interest has occurred."** : Do not do this. If your app isn't currently in the foreground then what makes you think the user wants you to display anything in front of what they are currently doing? They may be playing a game, typing an email, watching an online video etc etc. The correct way to do this is to create a `Notification` - it's non-intrusive and it allows the user to decide when (and if) they want to view it. Think about it - that's how facebook, twitter, email and SMS apps work.

Comment: okay, am going to launch the `Dialog` on clicking the `notification`. But the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

*Its not possible to launch a dialog without an activity's context.*

---

However,

You can make an activity look and feel like a dialog by adding this theme in your manifest:

```
       <activity
        android:name="YourActivityThatLooksLikeADialog"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Comment: Yeah, i wrote a `style` and added it to `styles.xml` to create the transparent effect. I just found out that the dialog pops up without the `Activity` as long as the `Activity` isn't running (it's completely closed). But, if i minimize the `Activity`, then the dialog pops up with the activity in the background. Any ideas?